# what is the model code to fetch multiple result set from store procedure in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

**My Model code is given below.**

```
   public function getattendence($data)
   {

        $sql="CALL `sp_AttendanceDetails`(?,?,?);";
        $query=$this->db->query($sql,$data);
        return $query->result_array();
   }
```

But it return one result set.The second result set i not get..

Comment: what is in `$data` ??

Comment: Please explain your code with controller

Answer (score 0):

Pass data like this

```
public function getattendence($data)
{
    # example of your $data array
    $id = $data['id'];
    $name = $data['name'];
    $date = $data['date'];

    $sql="CALL sp_AttendanceDetails($id,'$name',$date);";
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use return $this->_execute_multi_query($sql);
    refer http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php